# I need help converting PHP eregi_replace to preg

Tags: php, replace, deprecated, eregi

I know its a bit long. I'm trying to catch up on a deadline and if anyone could help me, I would gladly appreciate it. Another friend programmer of mine made this PHP script but unfortunately its already deprecated and doesn't work. Can anyone convert this to preg? I know nothing about eregi, preg, rejex, etc.

```
    function tolink($text){

    $text = " ".$text;

    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',

    '<a href="\\1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\\1</a>', $text);

    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tps://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',

    '<a href="\\1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\\1</a>', $text);

    $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)',

    '\\1<a href="http://\\2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\\2</a>', $text);

    $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4})',

    '<a href="mailto:\\1"  rel="nofollow">\\1</a>', $text);

    return $text;

    }
```

Comment: Yes but simply adding delimiters doesn't work.

Comment: why this question is -1. up voted!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wouldn't it be like this

```
  function tolink($text){
 $text = " ".$text;
 $text = preg_replace("/(((f|ht){1}tp:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/","<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">$1</a>", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/(((f|ht){1}tps:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/","<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">$1</a>", $text);
 $text = preg_replace("/([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/",
                      "$1<a href=\"http://$2\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">$2</a>", $text);

 $text = preg_replace('/([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4})/',
                      "<a href=\"mailto:$1\"  rel=\"nofollow\">$1</a>", $text);
 return $text;
```

}

you can also append `i` at the end of preg_replace pattern to make so that lowercase and uppercase character will be matched

this is what i mean

```
 preg_replace('/(((f|ht){1}tp:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/i' .....
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '/' in {PATH} on line 9

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '/' in {PATH} on line 13

Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '/' in {PATH} on line 17

Comment: I got those errors trying out your script. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: I guess was not paying attention. editing it now

Comment: I've edited it. can you also give me example usage of that function so that I can test it.

Comment: Also, it simply converts all URL inputs into no-follow and clickable links.